# Rails 5: unexpected network error while fetching information about the video

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm using [video_info](https://github.com/thibaudgg/video_info) gem to get informations about the vimeo videos. The account is private, the domain is declared on panel to load the videos. I have an initializer with the `VideoInfo.provider_api_keys`, just this line. From vimeo I use the **cliente identifier** as api key, I think it is ok.

The problem is, when I tried to retrieve information about the video I get the error

> unexpected network error while
>               fetching information about the video

**initializers/vimeo_api.rb**

```
VideoInfo.provider_api_keys = { vimeo: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' }
```

Someone got this error before?

Thanks!

Comment: The [method](https://github.com/thibaudgg/video_info/blob/68917647ee41dc2766952b2865bf45ec9fb5b826/lib/video_info/provider.rb#L82) that is causing the error. I guess there is some problem while reading the uri. Line #105 `JSON.load(uri.read)`. Why don't you try overriding the method ?

Comment: Thanks by help. Do you know any solution or alternative?

Comment: The error basically means that the http request failed, but it is not very specific about why exactly. The link @KedarnagMukanahallipatna posted, shows that in case of a 400 http code, a message is written to log suggesting the api key is invalid. Did you check if that message appears in your log before the error? Otherwise I aggree, you could override the method for debugging, so you find more information about why (how) the request failed.

Comment: If everything else looks good, it is quite likely that your api key is not valid. I am not sure what vimeos client identifier is, but here are instructions for retrieving an api key: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start

Comment: I've tested the autorization with https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/oauth/verify Vimeo the name cliend_id as api_key

Comment: Have you tried using their `API's` instead of the `gem` ? Looking at their documentation, they have detailed endpoints.